# Biztalk 2013 r2 DR SSO Issue

Tags: biztalk, disaster-recovery, biztalk-2013r2

Looking for help with a BizTalk disaster recovery scenario.

We have failed over to our DR server and have restored the database using the Microsoft standard log shipping method. All has run without issues but I cannot change any port settings in the administration console as the admin console is trying to connect to the original SSO servers.

This is the error displayed by the admin console is with just the server names removed. :-

Could not store transport type data for Primary Transport of Send Port 'DRTestAppSendPort' to config store. Both SSO Servers (Primary='{Old clustered SSO instance}' and Backup='{Old app server}') failed. Backup server failure: Could not contact the SSO server '{Old app server}'. Check that SSO is configured and that the SSO service is running on that server.
(Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM)

- The SampleUpdateInfo.xml has been updated correctly and the restore scripts have been run twice now from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2\Bins32\Schema\Restore.
- The BizTalk management DB contains the correct server name in the [adm_OtherDatabases]
- The registry settings are all correct after the scripts have run.
- SSOConfig –Status and the SSOAdministration utility report the
  correct DR app server as the master secret.
- The BizTalk group has been removed and re-added to the administration console.
- The SSO master secret has been restored successfully on the DR server.
- The windows management instrumentation service has been restarted..

Totally run out of ideas how to fix this, so any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does ssomanage show the correct SSO server name?

Comment: Thanks @Johns-305 - we did check that and it was correct.

Apologies - only spotted your response after I posted the details below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue's been resolved - there was a step missing in the Microsoft deployment guide, which is documented in a TechNet article.

Here's the step that was missing which has resolved the issue:

(Under Appendix 6):

7. Update the SSO Server name as displayed in the Group Properties dialog box available in the BizTalk Server Administration console. To update the SSO Server name, launch the BizTalk Server Administration console, click to expand BizTalk Server Administration, right-click the BizTalk Group node and select Properties to display the General tab of the BizTalk Server Administration console. Then enter the name of the Enterprise Single Sign-On server that this computer will use to access the configuration information for the adapters. This is the name of the SSO server used to connect to the SSO database.

Comment: Have you given feedback on that Guide to Microsoft so they can correct it?